# Odd icons in terminal Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: command-line, 22.04

When in terminal, I have on the left edge two symbols: a small right-pointing arrow and to its right a tilde. I have no idea where they came from nor how to get rid of them. So far, no effect on use.

Comment: a screenshot would be helpful

Comment: Let's see if I can make this happen.

Comment: It sounds like you're in the middle of running a command that expects input. Did you mess with `.bashrc`?